# How do I program a loop into a DDEPoke call on VBA?

Tags: vba

I am attempting to program a loop into a DDEPoke call to a VBA-supported function known as OPC.  This will enable me to write to a PLC (RSLogix 500) database from an excel spreadsheet.

This is the code:

```
Private Function Open_RsLinx()

On Error Resume Next
Open_RsLinx = DDEInitiate(RsLinx, C1)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error Connecting to topic", vbExclamation, "Error"
    OpenRSLinx = 0 'Return false if there was an error
End If


End Function

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

RsLinx = Open_RsLinx()
For i = 0 To 255

    DDEPoke RsLinx, "N16:0", Cells(1 + i, 2)

Next i
DDETerminate RsLinx

End Sub
```

This code works and will, if there is a link set up with an OPC server (in this case through RSLinx) write data to the PLC.

The problem is that I can't get the part `DDEPoke RsLinx, "N16:0", Cells(1 + i, 2)` to write data, sequentially, from one excel cell to one element of the PLC's data array.

I tried to do `DDEPoke RsLinx, "N16:i", Cells(1 + i, 2)` and `DDEPoke RsLinx, "N16:0+i", Cells(1 + i, 2)` but neither has any effect and the program doesn't write anything at all.

How can I set up the code to get N16:0 to increment all the way up to N16:255 and then stop?

Comment: So much fuzz for a simple syntax error in one line ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the variable `i` out of the string.  Be careful for the implicit type conversion though, depending on which (Str() or CStr()), you'll wind up with a leading space.  Thus, convert the number `Str(i)`, then wrap with `Trim()` to make sure there's no extra spaces, and concatenate that result back to your "N" string:

```
RsLinx = Open_RsLinx()
For i = 0 To 255

    DDEPoke RsLinx, "N16:" & Trim(Str(i)), Cells(1 + i, 2)

Next i
```

The reason the `i` didn't work when it's inside the string is because that in VBA, anything within a set of quotes is considered a literal string.  Unlike some other languages (PHP comes to mind) where variables can be resolved within a string like that, VBA must have variables concatenated.  Consider the following:

```
Dim s As String
s = "world"
Debug.Print "Hello s!"
```

This outputs the literal of `Hello s!` to the immediate window, because `s` is treated not as a variable, but as part of the literal string.  The correct way is through concatenation:

```
Dim s As String
s = "world"
Debug.Print "Hello " & s & "!"
```

That outputs the expected `Hello World!` to the immediate window, because `s` is now treated as a variable and is resolved and concatenated.

If that were not the case, the following might be difficult to deal with:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 to 9
  Debug.Print "this" & i
Next i
```

You would then have:

```
th0s0
th1s1
th2s2
th3s3
th4s4
'etc
```

That'd make things pretty difficult to manage in a lot of cases.

With all that said, there are some languages - notably PHP - where, when using a certain set of quotes (either `""` or `''` - I don't recall which offhand), in fact does resolve the variable when embedded into the string itself:

```
$i = 5;
echo "this is number $i";
```

VBA does not have this feature.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for the advice, jdl134679.  Why exactly will VBA not accept the variable "i" as an integer value and then interpret it as such when placed behind N16 as "N16:i"?

Comment: Thank you for the very succinct explanation,  That explains everything very clearly.  I can't express how much this has been helpful.